# Javascript + jQuery, applying a blur effect to background images

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to apply a "blur" effect on a background image in Javascript/jQuery?

[edit] By "blur" I mean a Gaussian/Motion blur not a drop shadow :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest, most cross-browser-friendly way to do this will be to create blurred and non-blurred versions of your background image ahead of time, and use JavaScript to swap the blurred version in when you want to. Something like:

```
$('#hoverMe').hover(function ()
{
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(blurredBackground.png)');
});
```

---

**Edit:** It's a bit of a cop-out, but all you need to do is create a new image element for Pixastic to operate on. Since Pixastic uses a canvas anyway, you can let the library do the work for you, and then just call [`toDataURL()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) to get a URL string. Then, pass that string back into the `background-image` CSS.

Very basic demo [here](http://jsbin.com/blur/8). Tested in Chrome, Firefox.

*Notes:*

- I couldn't get this to work in IE 8 in under 5 minutes (though it might be possible - Pixastic's [cross-browser support info](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#iesupport)) - I have no patience for IE.
- **The images you're blurring must be from the same origin (domain and subdomain) as the page you're blurring them in.** Otherwise, you'll get a security exception (and no blurring). This is a security feature of `canvas`, as per [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements). This is why my example image is jsbin's favicon, and not an image that's bigger/more interesting/from anywhere else.
- If you're doing any sort of repeated blurs of the same image, I would strongly recommend caching the result(s) of `toDataURL()` so the browser doesn't have to repeat its work. I don't know how `toDataURL()` works under the hood so this might not be entirely straightforward.

Happy blurring!

Comment: Thank you "bears will eat you", I was hoping to avoid multiplying all my images (130+) by 2

Comment: In that case, your best bet may be to use Pixastic, as VeeWee suggested, but replace your CSS `background-image` with [an `img` tag with low z-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image).

Comment: Seriously no way to do this then? :(

Comment: See my edit. Let me know if you absolutely must get this working in IE, but you might just be better off asking the Pixastic author to support canvas emulation in IE via [ExplorerCanvas](http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com).

Comment: @Bears will eat you - Lovely lovely lovely. Thank you for all your effort! (I have no patience for IE either, but I can work with this)

Comment: A serverside solution might be able to help, processing a duplicated image before it is even rendered, and knowing ahead of time what the generated image name will be, set it via CSS. Maybe this is a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572229/serverside-image-processing, maybe not - haven't looked around much, just commenting there may be improvements which will remove crossbrowser issues.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today, My solution was the following.
I used the regular way to use pixastic and blur an image.
Pixastic then in my case created a canvas element.
I made sure this canvas element had an id, and by getting its data, i used the data to set my background-image.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="width:0px; height: 0px;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.id = "blurredImage"
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blur", function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('blurredImage');
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById('blurredImage').style.backgroundImage = 'url("' +  dataURL + '")';
    });
}
document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").appendChild(img);
img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

It's quite a workaround, however I had to use floating divs, which made me unable to use position absolute, and z-index's and I won't blurr tons of images.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

There is this jquery-plugin blur.js which does what you are looking for.