# Adding MarvinFramework to a WebApp on Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, jersey, classloader, marvin-framework

I have a `Jersey` WebApp running on `Tomcat` and want to integrate the `MarvinFramework` for ImageProcessing. Basically I want to reduce noise, grayscale and scale an Image for further processing.

The [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) relies on custom Plugins for their specific prupose, and those Plugins I want to use. But since the Framwork has its own `ClassLoader`, that loads the plugins `JAR` dynamically at runtime from an absolute location inside the project, I am confused where to put the files or how to configure the WebApp, that the ClassLoader is able load the JARs. I recreated the directory-structure for standalone Apps inside my `WEB-INF/lib`-dir with the `Deployment Assembly` but I had no success.

I am getting a:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\marvin\plugins\image\org.marvinproject.image.color.grayScale.jar
```

when I try:

```
marvinImagePlugin = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.color.grayScale.jar");
```

the jar-file should be located by the deploment assebmly in:

```
WEB-INF/lib/marvin/plugins/image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the library path with `MarvinDefinitions.setImagePluginPath(path);` to a path of your choice. In this case you have to manually put the files to the JVM and they are not deployed automatically.

Comment: better than putting them in the JVM which can change its better to put it in a newtral path like /var/YourProjectname/v1/lib and point to that in sh or .bat file as a environment or system variable