# How to process the images at pixel level on server?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, marvin-framework, marvinproject

I want to develop Image Processing application on Linux server,I don't have any idea what library /programming language I must use. Is it possible to use OpenCV with java on server-side.I even heard about Marvin with java.This will be my first time attempt to develop application without Matlab.So please suggest any good image processing libraries for this purpose.

Comment: ^^ far too broad shot , unfortunately. try to focus on what you want to achieve, and ask a specific community specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use Marvin for this purpose. I've used Marvin with Tomcat Web Server for this purpose before. You can use other web server either. Just add marvin folder into your project and set the path as shown in this Stackoverflow discussion:

[Adding MarvinFramework to a WebApp on Tomcat7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602953/adding-marvinframework-to-a-webapp-on-tomcat7)

You might also ask for support on the project discussion group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/marvin-project